# How to automate TOTP login in zerodha

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate the TOTP login process in Zerodha using Selenium and java, but I am encountering an issue where the Chrome window opens up but does not navigate to the Zerodha login page. Instead, the window is empty with no content.

I have verified that the ChromeDriver version I am using is compatible with my Chrome browser version, and I have also ensured that the ChromeDriver executable file is in the PATH environment variable. However, the issue persists.

Here is the code I am using to automate the TOTP login in Zerodha:

```
        ChromeOptions cap = new ChromeOptions();
        cap.addArguments("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
        cap.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\karan\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();


        try {
            driver.get("https://kite.zerodha.com");

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

why above code is not navigating to the zerodha login page?

Comment: What error message are you getting? Edit it as text into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Zerodha {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    static {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "enter your chromedriver.exe file path");
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://kite.zerodha.com/");
}
}
```